# please I want code example in Fiddler to modify error messages

Tags: fiddler

I just need a code example to modify or remove errors handled by Fiddler when dns error occured

by using "OnReturningError" event or any other way

the error message that fiddler returns

[Fiddler] DNS Lookup for "somesite.com" failed. No such host is known

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer from [Vasiliy Alchakov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1394444/vasiliy-alchakov)

```
FiddlerApplication.BeforeReturningError += delegate(Session oS)
{
  oS.utilSetResponseBody(oS.GetResponseBodyAsString().Replace("[Fiddler]", String.Empty).Trim());
};
```